# How to call jquery timepicker inside a function

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using jquery time picker but before displaying the dropdown box to select time i need to perfom some validation and then display the option to select time but apparently it doesn't show the drop down **if called inside a function**
Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$("#cin").timepicker();
  $("#cin").on("click", function() {
    test(4, 4) //something to check
  })

  function test(test1, test2) {
    if (test1 == test2) {
      $("#cin").timepicker(); //Doesn't show on mouse click if keyboard down button press dropdown appears
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<input type="text" id="cin" autocomplete="off">
```

Drop down doesn't appear on mouse click **but if pressed with down button on keyboard it appears with half list**

Comment: The issue is because the timepicker is only instantiated on the first click. You need to blur/click again for the menu to then expand as the event handlers have now been attached

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and how would i do that ?

Comment: That depends on the timepicker plugin you're using. Do you have a link to their documentation?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan link to doc : http://timepicker.co/

Comment: It's not possible with the library you're using. That plugin is designed to be instantiated before first use, not on first use as you're trying to do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i just got an alternate solution in mind i am just gonna set it dynamically like this if(test1 == test2 {$("#cin").timepicker('option','timeFormat',"HH");})  while the timepicker will be instantiated outside only

Comment: Presuming you're doing that on load of the page, it'd work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah its onload only i just did and it worked :)

Comment: Glad you got it working :)